# Make request for Element Of Statistical Learning Dataset in Json format (C#)

Tags: json

Please I want to make request for this dataset [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/prostate.data](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/prostate.data) and get it in json format.
But when I run it, I get this error "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: l. Path '', line 1, position 1.". Below is the code I wrote using C#

```
public class Prostate
{
    public string lcavol { get; set; }
    public string lweight { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string lbph { get; set; }
    public string svi { get; set; }
    public string lcp { get; set; }
    public string gleason { get; set; }
    public string pgg45 { get; set; }
    public string lpsa { get; set; }
    public string train { get; set; }
    
}

    public async Task<Prostate> Data()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var resp = await client.GetAsync("https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/prostate.data");
        var repsStr = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var newdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(repsStr);
        Prostate somedata = (Prostate) newdata;
        return somedata;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I saved the file as txt and opened it in excel. I later saved it as csv then read it using this code

```
    public async Task<List<Prostate>> Files()
    {
        List<Prostate> prostates = new List<Prostate>();
        var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "[path to file]");

        string[] linesofdata = await System.IO.File.ReadAllLinesAsync(file);

        foreach(string line in linesofdata){
            string[] linewords = line.Split(',');
            Prostate newprostate = new Prostate();
            newprostate.lcavol = linewords[0];
            newprostate.lweight = linewords[1];
            newprostate.age = linewords[2];
            newprostate.lbph = linewords[3];
            newprostate.svi = linewords[4];
            newprostate.lcp = linewords[5];
            newprostate.gleason = linewords[6];
            newprostate.pgg45 = linewords[7];
            newprostate.lpsa = linewords[8];
            newprostate.train = linewords[9];

            prostates.Add(newprostate);
        }

        return prostates.ToList();
    }
```